# What would be the Typescript type for a module path? (for IDE autocompletion and static checking)

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA on my Typescript project and I'm loading certain modules dynamically. Is there any way to set to a variable/argument a type that corresponds with a path to a module/file?

I'm asking because I'd like to have the same autocomplete and warnins/errors effect I'm having when using require function or import operators but on a variable. Something like:

```js
const MODULE_PATH: Module_Path = '../my/Module/Path'
```

The alternative is using the type `string`.

I've inspected the editor's built-in types used by the `require` function and the argument type is a `string`. Is there any other way to achieve the desired effect in the editor?